# Writing Quad word to device register in PCI config space

Tags: driver, intel, freebsd, pci

My problem is I cannot write a 64 bit wide setting into a device register. I am working with a Intel® Xeon® Processor C5500/ C3500 Series with integrated memory controller and FreeBSD 10 based environment.

The data sheet (Intel® Xeon® Processor C5500/ C3500 Series Datasheet - Volume 2) mentions in section (4.12.40 Error Injection Implementation) the register MC_CHANNEL_x_ADDR_MATCH (which is a quad word access) should be set for ECC injection, but pci_cfgregwrite does not write 64 bit wide in port mapped I/O mode and the data sheet does not mention a base address for the register to help with memory mapping it. Tried to split the write into 2 32bit writes via pci_cfgregwrite but that does not help. How can I write a 64 bit wide setting into this register (Device: 4, 5, 6 Function: 0 Offset: F0h on bus 0xFF).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pci_cfgregwrite() writes to PCI configuration space and it does only 32-bit access.

I am pretty sure that your register is not located in PCI configuration space but in one of the PCI memory mapped address spaces that are described by Base Address Register 0/1/2/... (BAR0/1/2/...)

In order to access BARx regions you first map them to memory, then you use macros provided by FreeBSD for accessing the memory mapped regions. In your case, bus_space_write_8() would write 64bit.  http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/9/bus_space_write_8/

For more information, check FreeBSD documentation:
http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/arch-handbook/pci-bus.html